# jQuery .on() doesn't fire on click but instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button, I change its ID and apply a new style to it by adding a class `toMenu`. What I wanted to do is, when I click the button with the new ID `menu`, that it adds another class `menuTransition`. But what now happens is that it already adds the class `menuTransition` when I click the button with the old ID `#button`. But what it's supposed to do, is not add the class `menuTransition` until the button with the new ID `#menu` is clicked.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click(function(){
                $("#button").addClass("toMenu")
                $("#button").attr("id","menu");
    });
});
$(document).on("click", "#menu", function() {
        $("#menu").addClass("menuTransition");
});
```

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier (the problem itself would become moot) if you don't change the `id`.  Identifiers really shouldn't need to be changed, why are you doing that?  What's the goal of this code?

Comment: Yeah, your code doesnt make much sense... Just have the menu as an ID from the start and you wont have any issues.

Comment: The thing is, the button is not a menu first. Then it slides to the left and gets an individual style and get the id `menu`.

Comment: IMHO there's never a good reason to change the ID of an existing element.   IDs should be static, classes may be dynamic.

Comment: It would be possible with classes only, but it's easier for me to handle with the context of my code. Everyone got their individual way to code :)

Comment: @TobiasGlaus fair enough, but (no disrespect intended) - yours is wrong.

Comment: Also, having a static ID allows you to avoid the relatively inefficient binding on `$(document)` which causes the click event to be registered on the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a bit of a race condition. With your button click event handler you're adding a class and an ID to your button. Then with your delegated event handler you're looking for any clicks on the document, even those that bubble up from descendant elements, and adding a class there as well. One way to handle this is to add a small (~ 1 msec) delay to short-circuit this race that would normally occur with your example code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#button").addClass("toMenu")
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#button").attr("id", "menu");
    }, 1)
  });
});
$(document).on("click", "#menu", function() {
  $("#menu").addClass("menuTransition");
});
```

```css
.toMenu {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menuTransition {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
  button
</button>
```

By adding the 1 millisecond delay, the ID is added after the click on the button has reached the document event handler, so that event handler only fires after the first click on the button.

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked. I thought already, that it adds the id too early maybe, but what I tried is to add a `.delay(1)`, which didn't work. Your answer is working perfectly tho :)

Comment: @TobiasGlaus Please, don't do this.  Fix your code not to change the ID instead.  It'll be better in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be changing the ID.  Element IDs are intended to be static.  You can use a class to tag the current state of the button / menu and make it behave accordingly (and at the same time avoid the inefficient delegated event handler on `$(document)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menubutton").on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('toMenu')) {
           $this.addClass('menuTransition');
        } else {
           $this.addClass('toMenu');
        }
    });
});
```